# How to call addTarget:action:forControlEvents: from a class method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, oop

I am trying to use a single class method to instantiate a `UIButton`, based on the payload I pass in, as well as add an action handler, like this:

```
+ (void)instantiate: (UIButton *)button with:(NSDictionary *)payload {
  [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  button.title = payload.title;
}
```

Normally I don't have a problem if the `instantiate:with:` method was an ordinary method, but I don't know how to implement the `buttonClicked:` method in this case.

Should it be a class method? Should it be an instance method? Also If I need to make it a class method, how do I specify the `@selector` inside the `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` call?

Comment: You don't have access to self in class methods.

Comment: What is supposed to be self in your case? The button itself? What's that class? A singleton of that class ?

Comment: @Lubakis Sure you do - self references the actual class when used inside class methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People may debate whether using a class method or an instance method is better in this case but I'll simply answer the coding question.

You can use a class method if you want. The implementation of your `instantiate:with:` method is fine as-is. Just add the `buttonClicked:` method. It needs to be class method:

```
+ (void)buttonClicked:(UIButton *)button {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Is it ok to just add self as target? (for example instead of self.class)

Comment: `self` is the class inside a class method. So yes, just using `self` for the target is correct.